# "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" error while testing a Nodejs project with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jestjs

So I'm working on a Nodejs project with expressjs and I'm trying to use Jest to test my apis.
I've read about configuring Jest in the documentation, but I'm new to jest and it's a bit confusing.
The error I'm getting :

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)

My test file:

```
const userController = require("../controllers/user.controller");
const router = require("../routes/user.routes");


//Testing login route
describe("POST /api/user/login", () => {
    describe("given a username and password", () => {
  
      test("should respond with a 200 status code", async () => {
        const response = await request(router).post("/login").send({
          username: "username",
          password: "password"
        })
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200)
      })
     })
  

  
  })
```

Comment: Does your `package.json` have `"type": "module"` in it?

Comment: [So many possible duplicates](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22Cannot+use+import+statement+outside+a+module%22+jest+site%3Astackoverflow.com) (but I haven't done enough with Jest to be sure if any are a good match). [This question really needed more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) though.

Comment: I've done my research and I've seen many similar questions with the same error statement but none of them were about nodejs nor javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install **babel-jest**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.2",
    "jest": "^28.1.2",
    "supertest": "^6.2.4"
  }
```

and added a file called **.babelrc** to my project containing this code:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  }
```